# Statics Find the range value of P

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

[image]

Answer is $29.3 N ≤ P ≤ 109.3 N$

I tried solving it for quite some time already which I don't understand why I don't get the values. Can someone help me?

$Fv$ Vertical force $Fh$ Horizontal force $Na$ Normal force

I know that Body A has a $ΣFv=0$ is equal to $120=(Na)cos30$ and an $Fh=(Na)sin30$ then I tried to do an FBD on block B but I still can't get the answer I also know that $Fmax=Na(0.2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the reaction between the blocks, so $N\cos 30=120$

Let $X$ be the reaction from the floor on the lower block, and $F$ be the friction

Then we have$$N\cos 30 +80 =X\Rightarrow X=200$$
Also, $$N\sin 30\pm F=P$$
Assume friction is limiting, so $F=0.2\times 200=40$

Thus we have $$P=69.282\pm 40$$
Then we have the answer.